# perl File::Find and _

Tags: perl, stat

I am using `File::Find` to go through a ton of files and then doing cleanup based on their size, age etc. I am accessing these files through windows network shares so the stat calls are expensive

The code looked something like this

```
sub findItems
{
  my $item = $File::Find::name;
  my $dir  = $File::Find::dir;
  my $itemName = $_;

  if    (-f $item) { .. }
  elsif (-d $item) { .. }

  my $age = -M $item;
  my $size = -s $item;
```

Figured out that it was taking a lot of time. The culprit was the 3 calls `-f/-d`, `-M` and `-s`, all needing a fresh `stat`. So I changed it to

```
sub findItems
{
  my $item = $File::Find::name;
  my $dir  = $File::Find::dir;
  my $itemName = $_;

  if    (-f $item) { .. }
  elsif (-d $item) { .. }

  my $age = -M _;
  my $size = -s _;
```

This almost halved the time as I went from 4 `stat` calls to 2. I said 4 because I know there is one `stat` call in `File::find` as well, and 3 are in my code.

My question is can I rely on the `stat` call in `File::Find` and change my code to this

```
sub findItems
{
  my $item = $File::Find::name;
  my $dir  = $File::Find::dir;
  my $itemName = $_;

  if    (-f _) { .. }
  elsif (-d _) { .. }

  my $age = -M _;
  my $size = -s _;
```

This will again halve the time it takes. I guess I will have to actually check the `File::Find` code to see if there might be some other `stat` call on anything other than `$item`

thanks

Comment: "_can I rely on the `stat` call in `File::Find`_" -- probably, but I wouldn't.  Relying only on what you can see (and control) in your code is only one more call, right?  Might as well make one explicit call to `stat` (or `File::stat`) to retrieve upfront all you need.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [its documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find), "It is guaranteed that an *lstat* has been called before the user's wanted() function is called. This enables fast file checks involving _. Note that this guarantee no longer holds if follow or follow_fast are not set."

So I'd suggest that, under any other circumstance, you cannot rely on it.